# Only one argument in modular inverse

Tags: modular-arithmetic

https://www.codechef.com/FEB18/problems/BROCLK. This is the link of current codechef challenge.

In the output format it's written that "Let's denote the modular inverse of $q$ (it's guaranteed that the modular inverse exists and is unique) by $r$.". I am having difficulty in understanding this line because I have always read modular inverse of a number with respect to another number.

Is it there a default divisor which we use in case it's not present.I am not asking for solution of problem just the language issue.Please help.

Comment: "Let's denote the modular inverse of q by **r**". Isn't it the thing?!

Comment: No, I think we need to store the result of operation in r ,it's not the case that we need to take modular inverse wrt r, because r is not defined previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means

$$r \equiv q^{-1} \pmod{10^9+7}$$

The reason why they stated $\gcd(q, 10^9+7)$ exists is to ensure that $q^{-1} \pmod{10^9+7}$ exists.

Comment: Can you explain how did you infer this?

Comment: see edit. Also, the real reason is .... from experience.

Comment: OK... I will try this .... thanks